# How to require to reboot to stop a service in systemd?

Tags: systemd

I want to have a service that will always run as long as the system is booted, and if the user wants to stop it, they would have to reboot (for security reasons), otherwise it will keep running.

Does systemd even has this option? I've looked far and wide and came up with nothing.

Edit: I want the service to be running as long as the system is running, regardless of any action of a user. Probably make the system shut down if the service stops? The point is to make it impossible for it to not to run, and if it stops, the whole system should shut down.

Comment: To be clear, you want this service to to continue to run regardless of any action by a user? Does this include root and/or a user who otherwise has sudoer rights to stop the service or kill its process? Is the service to continue running even if there is something else with the system that might cause it to stop? Add this information to question by editing it. Don't reply in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

From `man systemd.unit` see `Requires=` and [`BindsTo=`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/latest/systemd.unit.html#BindsTo=)

When you say "the system", I am assuming you mean `multi-user.target`, but you could replace that with `basic.target`, `default.target`, `graphical.target`.

If we consider the man page, we can say `multi-user.target` Requires= `your.service`.  Then the man page would read:

```
Requires=
    multi-user.target gets activated, your.service will be activated as well.
    If your.service fails to activate, and an ordering dependency After= on
    your.service is set, multi-user.target will not be started.
```

If we say `multi-user.target` BindsTo= `your.service` we get something that might be even better:

```
BindsTo=
    In addition to the effect of Requires= it declares that if 
    your.service is stopped, multi-user.target will be stopped too.

    When used in conjunction with After= on the same unit the
    behaviour of BindsTo= is even stronger. In this case, 
    your.service has to be in active state for multi-user.target
    to also be in active state.
```

Adding the `Requires=` relationship is trivial. In `your.service`, add the following:

```
[Install]
RequiredBy=multi-user.target
```

Adding `BindsTo=` is more difficult.  You'll need to add a "drop-in" to `multi-user.target`.

```
$ systemctl edit multi-user.target
[Unit]
BindsTo=your.service
```